# Mouse movement / mouseover and JavaScript evaluation in watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, firewatir

I have a JavaScript-heavy Rails app which I am testing in watir. I have two specific testing requirements:

- I need to be able to simulate moving the mouse to a specific area of the screen (or at least triggering the onmouseover event for a div)
- Evaluating a snippet of JavaScript once the above has happened to see if a flag is set correctly

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in watir. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I found this to be really easy to do with Selenium, so I ended up using it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

```
browser.div(:id, "some-id").fire_event "onmouseover"
```

I have no idea how to solve the second question. You could ask at [watir-general](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following page for mouse controls:

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Right+Click+an+Element