# Mousemove in Watir

Tags: watir

How do you simulate a mousemove event in watir?

I have a mildly fancy object that cares about the exact position of the mouse within that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If firing the javascript mouseover event isn't specific enough...

```
browser.div(:id, "some-id").fire_event "onmouseover"
```

*source: [Mouse movement / mouseover and JavaScript evaluation in watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421095/mouse-movement-mouseover-and-javascript-evaluation-in-watir)*

...then you can try pairing Watir and autoit as described here to put the cursor in a specific location:
http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm

```
browser.autoit.MouseMove(x,y)
```

If using Windows, Win32ole will also make use of autoit.  There's a lot of this action documented in the 'how to handle pop-ups' section of the Watir FAQ.  http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups

```
require 'win32ole'
a=WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
a.mousemove 100,100
a.mousemove 300,300
a.mouseclick "right"
```

source: http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/4fa59dc4a33c58dd/451d5b72e5c37c63?lnk=gst&q=autoit+mousemove#451d5b72e5c37c63

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I'm on a Mac, so I wound up just using jQuery to generate a click event with appropriate pageX and pageY.

Comment: Glad to hear - you should post your code and accept it as the answer to this topic.